# Extjs3.4 How to override the constructor

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a need to override native constructor of one of Extjs classes. If to be more exact Ext.ensible.cal.DragZone, it is from extensible calendar.

What I have tried, and what solutions I have found

1. Put desired code to original code, but I want to avoid original code modifications. All my changes I want to keep in one place
2. Ext.override - it doesn't work. native constructor is called anyway
3. Fully duplicate the code from original library, but with my changes. 
   **Ext.ensible.cal.DragZone = Ext.extend(Ext.dd.DragZone, {.....
   });**
   But this causes some other unexpected error, seems that not all functionality is called(some of fields of the class, seems not to be properly initialized). But if I just put this code, instead of original, everything works fine(but see #1)
4. Create my own Ext.ensible.cal.DragZone by extending the original. Problem of this method, is that I need to review all the code of library, and override and/or extend all other classes which uses this DragZone, to make them to use mine.

So can you advise me smth. The most correct solution for me seems to be just constructor overriding.

How I overriding:

```
Ext.override(Ext.ensible.cal.DragZone, {
    constructor : function () {
        ...
    }
});
```

But as I told, original constructor is called

Comment: Overrides have worked for me in the past for a constructor. Please post the code that isn't working. Having said that, you should only override it is a bug and you expect them to fix it.  Creating your own subclass is the way to make your code affect the least amount of code possible, then only code that you choose to use your subclass will be affected,  it's a bit of work upfront but then you're less likely to have problems

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack you can try, remember that the class name is the constructor, there is actually no constructor property on the class that is generated

```
Ext.ensible.cal.DragZone = function () {
    // This is not very nice, it'd be better if you didn't have to 
    // assume what the parent is, but since we're already hacking it...
    Ext.dd.DragZone.apply(this, arguments) ;
    // Your code here
}
```

Note that this is not the safe approach as I mentioned in my comment,  but should work

I suggest you use approach 4 so that your modifications only apply to classes that choose to use it.

Comment: Thanks. But this approach will firstly execute the original code, of constructor, if I'm not mistaken. And I don't need this. I need to replace some original code with my own.

Comment: Easy enough. Don't call the original oldCtor.apply()? I put it there because not calling the super method is usually a code smell.  And it means that your fix is more likely to break as they change their code. Another reason why your own subclass is a better idea

Comment: Error ocured. I need to call superclass's constructor - Ext.ensible.cal.DragZone.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments); But in this approach superclass isn't defined

Comment: Store the super's constructor before you override it. Edited answer to reflect that

Comment: Eh.. I can't understand what happening, but this approach produce other error. So thanks you for your time. Seems overriding constructor is really very bad idea :)

Comment: @VadymKovalenko Added one last try, they keep getting hackier and hackier, this new approach requires knowing what the superclass of DragZone, I think this will work :)